# Continuous Joint conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I am have been trying to do the following problem.

Suppose X, Y are two continuous random variables with joint probability
density function:

$$f_{XY}(x,y)= \begin{cases} 12xy(1-x) & 0 <x,y<1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

find $P(Y<\frac{1}{2} | X > \frac{1}{2})$.

My attempt is the following:

We note that $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_y(y)}=\frac{12xy(1-x)}{\int_0^112xy(1-x)\text{d}x=2y}=6x(1-x).$$  This implies that $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ i.e. X and Y are independent.  Using this we do the following $$\begin{align*}P\left(Y<\frac{1}{2}|X>\frac{1}{2}\right)&=\frac{P\left(Y<\frac{1}{2},X>\frac{1}{2}\right)}{P\left(X>\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\&=\frac{P\left(Y<\frac{1}{2}\right)P\left(X>\frac{1}{2}\right)}{P\left(X>\frac{1}{2}\right)}\\&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}2y\text{d}y=\frac{1}{4}\end{align*}$$  The formula given to me was this $$F_{X|Y}(x|y)=P(X\le x|Y=y)=\int_{-\infty}^xf_{X|Y}(t|y)\text{d}t.$$  I guess my attempt is correct but it lead me to the question of what if X and Y were **not independent** would the formula then just be $$\begin{align*} F_{X|Y}(x|y)&=P(X\le x|Y\le y)\\&=\frac{P\left(X\le x,Y \le y \right)}{P\left(Y \le y \right)}\\&=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y f_{XY}(u,v)\text{d}v\text{d}u}{\int_{-\infty}^y f_Y(v)\text{d}v} \end{align*}.$$

Comment: Your setup in terms of integrals towards the end is correct.  Things are a little diifferent if we want say $\Pr(Y\le 1/4\mid X=1/2)$. Then we need to find the conditional density of $Y$ given that $X=1/2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. You did not need it!